# Horizontal Rule not displaying once CSS attributes added

Tags: html, css, horizontal-line

The HR displayed perfectly fine until I changed its class attributes.      The intention was to change a basic black line to a different color, and size. No error messages, and upon inspection in Chrome Dev Tools, the horizontal rule is loading, but not displaying. I have changed the attributes in Chrome Dev and in my IDE with no success. It should display a thick red HR.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: serif;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr {
  border: 10px red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <div class="class1-row">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu.</p>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="class2">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, biben</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You used the shorthand `border` property but left out the style part, which makes it default to none

Comment: You simply missed the border-style, use solid, Like I have mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Add some border-style:

```
hr{
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! The documentation I could find didn't work, but a quick StackOverflow question and my site is back to being pretty. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer helped you,,,, please accept it by clicking the tick icon left to my answer And you are welcome my friend :)

Comment: I click it for him... x)

Comment: Thanks! Do not have the Stackoverflow rep yet.

Comment: Ohhh, I see!  Let me give you some reputation :) Enjoy Mate !!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `solid` to your border:

```
border: 5px solid red;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: serif;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr {
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <div class="class1-row">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu.</p>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="class2">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, biben</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: You copy my answer!

Comment: Wrong --  My answer was 2 minutes BEFORE yours  .. Look at the timestamp.

Comment: @Zak: Zak you are right? and Nathaniel Please grow up buddy:) Why should someone copy stuff:)

Answer (score 0):

Add `solid` attributes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: serif;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr {
  border: 10px solid red; /* solid attributes */
  border-radius: 3px;
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <div class="class1-row">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu.</p>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="class2">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, biben</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I answered the same way 1 min earlier ..

Comment: @Zak: Correct :)

Comment: okay I'm sorry...